# map function do not modifying the current array in javascript and return new array with modified

Tags: javascript

is map return new array or modify the existing array in java script?
i have an example  in these example map should not modify the current array(not working) but it should modified array (its working fine),

```
let x = [{ 'name': 'a', checked: false },
{ 'name': 'b', checked: true },
{ 'name': 'c', checked: false }];
```

changing x based on the y name

```
let y = [{ 'name': 'a', checked: true },
{ 'name': 'b', checked: true },]
```

map function

```
y.forEach(ele =>{
  boss= x.map(item =>{
    if(ele.name == item.name){
      item.checked = true;
    }
    return item;
  });
});
```

expected output

```
x = [{"name":"a","checked":false},{"name":"b","checked":true},{"name":"c","checked":false}]
```

and

```
boss = [{"name":"a","checked":true},{"name":"b","checked":true},{"name":"c","checked":false}]
```

[example sackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jxmmyd?file=index.js)

Comment: it depends. but what is the real question?

Comment: Map function is returning new array

Comment: expected x value is different in sackblitz. x before and after should be same right? why it is modifying i dont understand

Comment: @Isaac correct, but it should  not modified x values right is my code is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map new objects by taking an empty object and assign the actual object and the wanted update property with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var array = [{ name: 'a', checked: false }, { name: 'b', checked: true }, { name: 'c', checked: false }],
    update = [{ name: 'a', checked: true }, { name: 'b', checked: true }],
    updateMap = new Map(update.map(({ name, checked }) => [name, { checked }])),
    updatedArray = array.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, updateMap.get(o.name)));

console.log(updatedArray);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i dont understand line 3 and 4 in your code , can you give some info?

Comment: line 3: it builds a `Map` out of the given update array and takes `name` as key and an object with `checked` as property. line4: [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) takes an empty array as target, adds the given object and takes the value of the map, if exists. the result is a new object, without any reference to the old object (in this case).